# Not able to enter password for few seconds at login screen in Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, login-screen, wayland, 23.04

I am using [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) 23.04 on HP Pavilion laptop.
Everything is working fine except one problem at login screen.

I am not able to type a password for the first few seconds(around 10 seconds). Nothing gets typed in the input box of password at the login screen. After a few seconds the input box start taking input.

I try clicking on input field still not able to type password. I have to wait for few seconds to type password.

I am facing this in both [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) and [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(protocol)).

How can I trubleshhot and fix this bihaviour?

I observed errors in `journalctl` related to `kwin_libinput` and `xkbcommon`

```
Jul 23 07:36:46 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
Jul 23 07:36:46 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kernel: mei_pxp 0000:00:16.0-fbf6fcf1-96cf-4e2e-a6a6-1bab8cbe36b1: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_pxp_tee_component_ops [i915])
Jul 23 07:36:46 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2561]: kwin_libinput: Libinput: client bug: timer event6 tap: scheduled expiry is in the past (-128ms), your system is too slow
Jul 23 07:36:46 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2561]: kwin_libinput: Libinput: client bug: timer event6 hold: scheduled expiry is in the past (-268ms), your system is too slow
Jul 23 07:36:46 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2561]: kwin_libinput: Libinput: client bug: timer event6 tap: scheduled expiry is in the past (-61ms), your system is too slow
Jul 23 07:36:46 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2561]: kwin_libinput: Libinput: client bug: timer event6 hold: scheduled expiry is in the past (-201ms), your system is too slow
Jul 23 07:36:46 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kernel: done.
```

```
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kernel: br-a31a159f0d45: port 1(vethe405932) entered blocking state
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kernel: br-a31a159f0d45: port 1(vethe405932) entered forwarding state
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:39:34: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:40:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:41:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:42:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:43:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:44:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:45:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:46:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:47:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:48:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:49:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:49:29: too many errors
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: xkbcommon: ERROR: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:49:29: failed to parse file
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx krunner[3645]: qt.qpa.input.methods: failed to create compose table
Jul 23 08:05:38 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

```
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: No backend specified, automatically choosing drm
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:39:34: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:40:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:41:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:42:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:43:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:44:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:45:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:46:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:47:27: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:48:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:49:29: string literal is not a valid UTF-8 string
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:49:29: too many errors
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose:49:29: failed to parse file
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: OpenGL vendor string:                   Intel
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: OpenGL renderer string:                 Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: OpenGL version string:                  4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.2
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: Driver:                                 Intel
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: GPU class:                              Tiger Lake
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: OpenGL version:                         4.6
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: GLSL version:                           4.60
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: Mesa version:                           23.0.2
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: Linux kernel version:                   6.2
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: Requires strict binding:                no
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: GLSL shaders:                           yes
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: Texture NPOT support:                   yes
Jul 23 08:05:25 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: Virtual Machine:                        no
Jul 23 08:05:26 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: inet:323:58: unrecognized keysym "XF86EmojiPicker"
Jul 23 08:05:26 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2790]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: inet:324:58: unrecognized keysym "XF86Dictate"
Jul 23 08:05:26 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2814]: (WW) Option "-listen" for file descriptors is deprecated
Jul 23 08:05:26 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2814]: Please use "-listenfd" instead.
Jul 23 08:05:26 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2814]: (WW) Option "-listen" for file descriptors is deprecated
Jul 23 08:05:26 alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx kwin_wayland_wrapper[2814]: Please use "-listenfd" instead.
```

Output of `lsusb` is

```
alok@alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx:~$ sudo lsusb 
[sudo] password for alok: 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain` is

```
alok@alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx:~$ sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @9.217s
└─multi-user.target @9.217s
  └─docker.service @5.646s +3.570s
    └─network-online.target @5.572s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.817s +3.755s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.788s +26ms
          └─dbus.service @1.736s +49ms
            └─basic.target @1.729s
              └─sockets.target @1.729s
                └─snapd.socket @1.727s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.666s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @1.574s +91ms
                      └─apparmor.service @1.535s +35ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.535s
                          └─run-docker-netns-412a5bd66398.mount @8.031s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @535ms
                              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @523ms +11ms
                                └─systemd-sysusers.service @515ms +7ms
                                  └─systemd-remount-fs.service @507ms +4ms
                                    └─systemd-journald.socket @488ms
                                      └─system.slice @399ms
                                        └─-.slice @399ms
```

Output of `sudo systemd-analyze blame` is

```
3.755s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
3.570s docker.service
3.347s fwupd-refresh.service
3.286s fwupd.service
2.756s apt-daily-upgrade.service
 782ms snapd.service
 472ms snapd.seeded.service
 289ms dev-nvme0n1p4.device
 211ms apport.service
 188ms systemd-journal-flush.service
 144ms containerd.service
 127ms user@1000.service
 121ms dev-loop5.device
 120ms dev-loop3.device
 120ms dev-loop6.device
 119ms dev-loop4.device
 119ms dev-loop2.device
 117ms dev-loop7.device
 116ms rsyslog.service
 116ms dev-loop1.device
 106ms udisks2.service
  98ms dev-loop0.device
  97ms plymouth-quit.service
  95ms ua-timer.service
  93ms accounts-daemon.service
  93ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  91ms snapd.apparmor.service
  88ms dev-loop9.device
  85ms dev-loop8.device
  79ms systemd-udevd.service
  76ms ModemManager.service
  71ms update-notifier-download.service
  63ms systemd-modules-load.service
  59ms systemd-resolved.service
  58ms avahi-daemon.service
  57ms systemd-journald.service
  56ms bluetooth.service
  51ms power-profiles-daemon.service
  49ms dbus.service
  49ms polkit.service
  48ms systemd-logind.service
  45ms gpu-manager.service
  42ms cups.service
  38ms upower.service
  38ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-788B\x2d6455.service
  36ms thermald.service
  36ms secureboot-db.service
  35ms apparmor.service
  33ms snap-firefox-2916.mount
  31ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-120.mount
  31ms alsa-restore.service
  30ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  29ms smartmontools.service
  28ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  27ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-68.mount
  27ms e2scrub_reap.service
  26ms keyboard-setup.service
  26ms NetworkManager.service
  26ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  25ms snap-snapd-18596.mount
  25ms docker.socket
  24ms snap-snapd-19457.mount
  23ms boot-efi.mount
  23ms snap-core22-806.mount
  23ms snap-bare-5.mount
  23ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  22ms snap-core22-817.mount
  22ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
  21ms snap-firefox-2517.mount
  19ms dev-hugepages.mount
  18ms kerneloops.service
  18ms dev-mqueue.mount
  17ms plymouth-start.service
  16ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  15ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  15ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  13ms grub-common.service
  13ms wpa_supplicant.service
  12ms systemd-binfmt.service
  11ms plymouth-read-write.service
  11ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  10ms systemd-sysctl.service
   9ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   8ms modprobe@configfs.service
   7ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   7ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
   7ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   7ms systemd-sysusers.service
   6ms modprobe@fuse.service
   5ms systemd-random-seed.service
   5ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   5ms modprobe@drm.service
   5ms console-setup.service
   4ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   4ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   2ms systemd-rfkill.service
   2ms sddm.service
   2ms rtkit-daemon.service
   2ms motd-news.service
   1ms ufw.service
   1ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   1ms setvtrgb.service
   1ms snapd.socket
```

Comment: Laptop hardware could sometimes be tricky, because of proprietary components (e.g. Keyboard, Mouse, ...). Can you add `lsusb` output to the question.

Comment: @Marco: added output of `lsusb`

Comment: Seems no USB Keyboard/Mouse. Have you tried if this happens with an external USB Keyboard, too?

Comment: @Marco: I do not use external keyboard and mouse. I will try with external keyboard

Comment: I have added `journalctl` logs which have errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possible reasons for this.

This could just be high system load, especially immediately after boot while services are still starting in the background.  The system, especially the GUI, can be unresponsive under these conditions.

A second possibility is that the video driver may still be initializing and it hasn't set the keyboard in the correct mode yet, so it can't accept input.  This is more of an issue with some video drivers than others.

There's not a lot that can be done to improve this.  If this is purely a boot issue, you might be able to use something like systemd-analyze to examine what services are starting and how long it takes each to complete.  Disabling slow things that are unnecessary might help, but be careful to not disable services you need.  It may also be possible to delay some service initializations so they are not all starting at once.

If this is a video driver issue, obviously changing video hardware might help, but faster video hardware typically is what has more complicated drivers that take longer to initialize, so this is probably not a useful solution.

Comment: I have added output of `systemd-analyze` in question

Comment: I have added `journalctl` logs which have errors.